# Appending a named number vector to a matrix with more values

Tags: r, data-analysis

Im relatively new to R, and I just cant seem to find the solution to this problem, so sorry if this might be obvious or has been asked before.

I have a large matrix, with named named rows. I filtered this data and performed a calculation with a subset of this filtered data. for the filtered data, I have managed to add the values i calculated into a new column.

original matrix

| Table 1 | Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Row 1 | 1 | 2 |
| Row 2 | 3 | 4 |
| Row 3 | 5 | 6 |

filtered Matrix with annotation in Column C

| Table 1 | Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Row 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| Row 3 | 5 | 6 | 11 |

original matrix with annotation only for filtered columns

| Table 1 | Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Row 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| Row 2 | 3 | 4 | 0/NaN |
| Row 3 | 5 | 6 | 11 |

How do I add these annotation rows back to the original matrix, if the original matrix is larger?

Is there even this type of functionality in matrices or would I be better off converting all of the data to a dataframe and doing the calculations that way?

(edit formatting the tables)

Answer (score 0):

We may use a join

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(as.data.frame(m1), as.data.frame(m2))
```

---

Or in `base R` with `merge`

```
merge(as.data.frame(m1), as.data.frame(m2), all.x = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `match` on the row names, something like

```
original_matrix[, "Column C"] <- NA
original_matrix[match(rowNames(filtered_matrix), rowNames(original_matrix)), "Column C"] <- filtered_matrix[, "Column C"]
```

Though generally I would prefer data frames for this type of operation.